# Is this house rule going to be overpowered?

Tags: house-rules, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

For the long time I thought about Celerity and Potence giving their wielder an additional bonus to a respective stat. This always seemed to be such an interesting concept, so I wanted to add such a thing to every Discipline.

Some other Disciplines give you a passive bonus to some Trait, just like Celerity in V20, the bonus equals Discipline rating. Traits still cannot exceed 10, and the bonus may not exceed your base stat level: if you have Obfuscate 4 and normal Stealth of 3, your effective Stealth is 6, and if you buy just one level of Stealth, you also “unlock” one from Obfuscate and your effective Stealth becomes 8.

Bonus to social stats:

- Dominate — Manipulation
- Presence — Charisma
- Chimerstry — Appearance

Bonus to mental stats:

- Auspex — Perception
- Mytherceria — Intelligence
- Dementation — Wits

Ability bonus:

- Animalism — Animal Ken
- Obfuscate — Stealth
- Vicissitude — Medicine
- Obeah — Empathy, may substitute Medicine for Empathy in any roll.

Fortitude (in vanilla) essentially gives you additional Stamina that works always. And, from my point of view, is generally weaker than two other Disciplines.
So I decided to add it an *active* effect: as a reflexive action, you may get guaranteed soak successes against one attack targeted against you that round (the amount equals your Fortitude), spending one blood point per each attack (so the amount of such actions is only limited by Generation). Can only be used against bashing or lethal damage. Of course, you need to be aware of the attack.

**Is it all going to become overpowered, or ruin the game some other way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would highly recommend against this.  I am using the V20 rules for my answer.

Celerity you pay for every usage or get no bonus.

Fortitude and Potence add bonus dice passively, but require payment for *free* successes, which lasts the turn - not per attack.  This is (ostensibly) for balance

Auspex already decreases perception difficulties by its level as the Heightened Senses ability.

Frankly, the listed disciplines you want to modify already have powerful affects on the types of rolls you mentioned.  To add more to them would definitely imbalance the game especially comparing kindred to other beings.  For example at char gen, 5 Freebie points gets me one of those traits.  7 Freebie points gets me that same trait plus a discipline.